# where clause in linq query

Tags: asp.net, linq

in the below code `transmittalno.TransID` always has value but `doctranstocon.Transid` sometimes has value and sometimes does not, so when `doctranstocon.Transid` has value I have no problem but when there is not any value, when compare in the where clause like :`transmittalno.TransID == doctranstocon.Transid`. 
It returns error " **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**"

```
TranstoCons = from doctranstocon in _DocTranstoCons where 
              ( transmittalno.TransID == doctranstocon.Transid  ) 
              select doctranstocon.tblTranstoCon
```

I like TranstoCons returns null when there is not any value for " doctranstocon.Transid  "

How I can handle this error in the below linq query:

```
var query = from transmittalno in _Transmittals
            Select new TransmittaltoConPresentationModel 
            { 
              TransID = transmittalno.TransID, 
              Transmittal = transmittalno.TRANSMITTAL, 
              TranstoCons = from doctranstocon in _DocTranstoCons where 
                            ( transmittalno.TransID == doctranstocon.Transid  ) 
                            select doctranstocon.tblTranstoCon 
             };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
where doctranstocon != null && doctranstocon.Transid.Equals(transmittalno.TransID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from transmittalno in _Transmittals
            Select new TransmittaltoConPresentationModel 
            { 
              TransID = transmittalno.TransID, 
              Transmittal = transmittalno.TRANSMITTAL, 
              TranstoCons = from doctranstocon in _DocTranstoCons 
                            where doctranstocon == null || transmittalno.TransID == doctranstocon.Transid
                            select doctranstocon != null? doctranstocon.tblTranstoCon : null
             };
```